# Save Clipboard image to .jpg

Tags: excel, powershell, charts, powerpoint

I've several Excel reports and need to export selected charts as images, as a first step. I then need to import these images into a PowerPoint presentation.
It seems I am almost there, yet stuck.

1. Am trying to get all charts of a worksheet with the method chartObjects (I've tried with the method chart, but then my collection was empty).

I then copy the selected chart as picture into the Clipboard (when this will be working, I will use forEach to get all of the charts of my workbook).

However, when I try to save the Clipboard data, it seems there are no pictures there, while there are data.

```
    $xl = new-object -c excel.application
    $xl.displayAlerts = $false
    $xl.visible = $false
    $wb = $xl.workbooks.open($fileData)
    $ws= $wb.sheets.Item("Sheet1")

    $chartCollect = $ws.chartObjects() 
    $chartToExport = $chartCollect.Item(3) 
    $toClipboard = $charToExport.copyPicture()

    $e=[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetDataObject()
    if ($e -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "there is no data"
    }

    $img =$e.GetImage()
    if ($img -eq $null) 
    {
        Write-Host "there is no picture"
    }

    $img.save("Path\test.jpg", "jpg")

    # I tried using the export method, but it does not exist with chartObjects
    $a = $chartToExport.Export("Path\test.gif", "GIF")
```

2. Skipping step 1, I tried to post directly the Clipboard data into the PowerPoint presentation, which is working.

However, I cannot place the imported picture as I wish. I tried in the same time to import picture for folders, and I then do not have trouble to play with their positions.

```
    $pptx = "Path\Presentation.pptx" 
    $pt = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
    $presentation = $pt.Presentations.open($pptx)
    $slide2 =  $presentation.slides.item(2)
    $slide3 =  $presentation.slides.item(3)

    # Paste the Clipboard chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
    # Works OK, but I do not success to place where I wish 
    $shape2 = $slide2.shapes.paste() 
    $shape2.Left = 10    # Does not work 
    $shape2.Top = 10     # Does not work

    # Test on existing picture, Works OK
    $imgTest = "Path\picture.jpg"
    $LinkToFile = $msoFalse
    $SaveWithDocument = $msoTrue
    $Left = 10
    $Top = 10
    $Width = 10
    $Height = 10
    $shape3 = $slide3.shapes.addPicture($imgPath, $LinkToFile, 
            $SaveWithDocument,$Left, $Top, $Width, $Height)
```

Does anyone know how to solve either or both of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the clipboard pasting in 2) import a .emf file. I tried to play with the .copyPicture method in 1) in order to export a .jpg format, but without success. (using: [copyPicture method description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.copypicture(v=office.14).aspx))

I also tried to follow the incrementLeft and incrementTop method to modify the position of the imported .emf file, but without success (using: [incrementLeft method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.incrementleft(v=office.14).aspx)). The error is: exception calling "incrementLeft" with "1" argument: exception from  HRESULT: 0x800A01A8

Does anyone know how to solve the above 2 issues?

Anyhow, I came up with a solution, not beautiful, but which is working for now until better one.

Solution for 2:

Before importing the clipboard image, I duplicate the target slide.

I then import the clipboard and then export the .emf file to a .jpg file.

I erase the duplicated slide and import the .jpg newly created file. I success then to modify the position of the he imported .jpg, while I could not do so with the .emf object.

```
    $slide2 =  $presentation.slides.item(2)
    $slide2Dup = $slide2.duplicate()
    $shape2 = $slide2Dup.shapes.paste()
    $a= $shape2.export("Path\export.jpg", $ppShapeFormatJPG)
    $slide2Dup.delete()
    $imgPath = 'Path\export.jpg'
    $LinkToFile = $msoFalse
    $SaveWithDocument = $msoTrue
    $Left = 10
    $Top = 10
    $Width = 10
    $Height = 10
    $shape2 = $slide2.shapes.addPicture($imgPath, $LinkToFile, 
        $SaveWithDocument,$Left, $Top, $Width, $Height)
```

In the same time, am getting a folder full of .jpg file corresponding to the excel chart, so 1) is somehow solved.